# How to convert this angular factory to typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

So, I have this 'constants' factory that just provides some constants to use in templates,models and controllers. In my angular controllers, I just do `constants.roles.ADMIN` normally. How would this translate into typescript?

```
(function() {
  'use strict';    
  angular.module('App').factory('constants',  function(){
    return {    
      roles: {
        ADMIN:'admin',
        CLIENT:'client',
        USER:'user'
      },    
      loginStatus: {
        LOGGED_OUT: 'loggedOut',
        LOGGED_IN: 'loggedIn',
        LOGGING_IN: 'loggingIn',
      },   
    };    
  });    
}());
```

I want something that kind of looks like this. Here's my attempt, but this seems to be incorrect. For now, I just put this in the same ts file as my model for testing purposes:

```
class constants {
      static roles:object {
        ADMIN:string = 'admin',
        CLIENT:string = 'client',
        USER:string = 'user'
      },    
      loginStatus: {
        LOGGED_OUT:string =  'loggedOut',
        LOGGED_IN:string =  'loggedIn',
        LOGGING_IN:string =  'loggingIn',
      },
  }

  class UserModel {
        //obviously this is just an example

        activeRole:string;

        isAdmin = () => {
            return this.activeRole == constants.roles.ADMIN;
        }
  }
```

but I can't jump to the definition and my syntax highlighting shows my static classes as an unused declaration.

I'm a total TS noob, so maybe I'm approaching this wrong. How should I translate from my factory to ts object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the Typescript version *([playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Aclass%20constants%20%7B%0A%09public%20static%20roles%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09ADMIN%20%20%3A%20'admin'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CLIENT%20%3A%20'client'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20USER%20%20%20%3A%20'user'%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%09public%20static%20loginStatus%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGED_OUT%20%3A%20'loggedOut'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGED_IN%20%20%3A%20'loggedIn'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGING_IN%20%3A%20'loggingIn'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20class%20UserModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fobviously%20this%20is%20just%20an%20example%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20activeRole%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isAdmin%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.activeRole%20%3D%3D%20constants.roles.ADMIN%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D))*:

```
class constants {
    public static roles = {
        ADMIN  : 'admin',
        CLIENT : 'client',
        USER   : 'user'
    };
    public static loginStatus = {
        LOGGED_OUT : 'loggedOut',
        LOGGED_IN  : 'loggedIn',
        LOGGING_IN : 'loggingIn',
    };
  }

  class UserModel {
        //obviously this is just an example

        activeRole:string;

        isAdmin = () => {
            // we need this. to access class member
            return this.activeRole == constants.roles.ADMIN;
        }
  }
```

*Also, `activeRole` must be accessed with `this`.*

Check it [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0Aclass%20constants%20%7B%0A%09public%20static%20roles%20%3D%20%7B%0A%09%09ADMIN%20%20%3A%20'admin'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CLIENT%20%3A%20'client'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20USER%20%20%20%3A%20'user'%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%09public%20static%20loginStatus%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGED_OUT%20%3A%20'loggedOut'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGED_IN%20%20%3A%20'loggedIn'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LOGGING_IN%20%3A%20'loggingIn'%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20class%20UserModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2Fobviously%20this%20is%20just%20an%20example%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20activeRole%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20isAdmin%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.activeRole%20%3D%3D%20constants.roles.ADMIN%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D)

Comment: ah, yeah i was just coding right in the SO window. Cool that makes sense. If i want to externalize this to its own class then, I would just put class Constants (i will uppercase it) in a file, and have that reference the project root ,  say app.ts and it works, or should I explicitly import it from my UserModel? I guess that's a whole different question....

Answer (score 0):

You obviously need `angular.constant` and not factory. Factory is good for cases where you need to do some calculations to create your object, or other services as injections. if you are using constant values, you should definitely use `angular.constant`, like this:

```
angular.module('App').constant('constants',  {    
      roles: {
        ADMIN:'admin',
        CLIENT:'client',
        USER:'user'
      },    
      loginStatus: {
        LOGGED_OUT: 'loggedOut',
        LOGGED_IN: 'loggedIn',
        LOGGING_IN: 'loggingIn',
      },   
    };    
  );
```

Another thing to mention, is that if you don't need different values for tests/dev I would suggest that you should use ES6 constant, and this will also help TypeScript detect type errors, refactor, in your IDE will "understand" your constant.